# Sending emails in django

Tags: django, email

I want to send email to the user whenever the user gets registered.
I have written a code for sending email in my forms.py

Below is the code snippet:

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.conf import settings

#User registration form
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
     email = forms.EmailField()  #default is required=True

    class Meta:
        model = User #user model will be affected

        fields = ['first_name','username','email','password1','password2']

    def send_email(self):
        name = self.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        to_email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        subject = 'Login details for Django_app'
        from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        context = {
            'name': name,
            'username': username,
            'email': to_email,
            'password': password,
        }

        plaintext = get_template('register_email.txt')
        htmly = get_template('register_email.html')
        text_content = plaintext.render(context)
        html_content = htmly.render(context)

        message = EmailMultiAlternatives(
            subject=subject,
            body=text_content,
            from_email=from_email,
            to=[to_email]
        )
        message.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
        message.send()
```

When i register a user email is not sent, can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that your `send_email()` method is never called !

You can eventually overload the model save method and call your method inside:

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()  #default is required=True

    class Meta:
        model = User #user model will be affected
        fields = ['first_name','username','email','password1','password2'] 

    # bla bla

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super().save(commit)
        self.send_email()  # there you send the email when then model is saved in db
        return instance
```

Another option is to use [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/),